# Profiling Windows Workflow Services

Tags: profiling, workflow-foundation, workflowservice, dotcover

What should I do to profile worflows exposed as Windows Workflow services? Which tool did you use?

I have tried to use dotTrace (jetBrains): I can see data in the profiling snapshot, but it seems I cannot see methods called by workflows.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the information you want to get out of it you can use AppFabric. Once installed you can go into IIS and set monitoring to "Troubleshooting" and get back pretty much everything the workflow has done.